# Can modern compilers devirtualize function calls when using dependency injection

Tags: c++

Dependency injection is a very important pattern when you want your code to be testable, and it is used all the time in big C++ projects.

Here is a simple example:

```
// Copyright 2019 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

class FooInterface {
  public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual ~FooInterface() = default;
};

class Foo : public FooInterface {
  public:
    void f() override { /* Actual work */ }
};

class MockFoo : public FooInterface {
  public:
    void f() override { /* Mock code */ }
};

class Bar {
  public:
    Bar(std::unique_ptr<FooInterface>&& foo) : foo_(std::move(foo)) { }
    void b() { foo_->f(); }

  private:
    std::unique_ptr<FooInterface> foo_;
};

// In production
void production() {
  auto bar = std::make_unique<Bar>(std::make_unique<Foo>());
  bar->b();
  // ...
}

// In tests
void test() {
  auto bar = std::make_unique<Bar>(std::make_unique<MockFoo>());
  bar->b();
  // ...
}
```

One doubt that I've always had is if compilers are able to devirtualize this kind of usage of virtual functions.

I know that in the general case it's impossible to know which derived class is being used, but in the example above the compiler knows which objects are being used in the `production` and the `test` functions, because they are being explicitly instantiated.

Can modern compilers optimize this special case and remove the virtual function calls given that they know which derived class is being instantiated at compile time?

If this specific example can't be devirtualized, is there any change that can be made to it so that the calls are devirtualized?

Comment: You can *help* the compiler, sometimes, by using the `final` keyword.

Comment: The only way to conclusively answer this for you is for you to compile your own code and look at the resulting output. I think there's only a very small chance that the compiler will devirtualize this, and pretty much un-possible if everything is in different translation units. But I also have to ask, why does it matter, in this day of multi-GHZ CPUs, and terabytes of ram.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It doesn't, just pure curiosity.

Comment: I tried compiling my own code but I don't have much experience reading LLVM IR, so it is a bit difficult to understand what is happening.

Comment: With `inline void* operator new(std::size_t n){return malloc(n);}`, gcc does devirtualize the calls. Otherwise, it is not sure if operator new might mess things up (change the dynamic type) so it leaves the virtual call alone (clang may have more assumptions about what operator new can or cannot do). That's probably quite representative of real code, where very often there will be something in the middle that breaks the devirtualization analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the compiler and the particular code you are dealing with. In my experience, you should not rely on it if you really care about avoiding `virtual` calls.

For instance, Clang/LLVM *will* devirtualize your example under `-O2` if `f()` is `noexcept`:

```
class FooInterface {
  public:
    virtual void f() noexcept = 0;
    virtual ~FooInterface() = default;
};
```

But other major compilers won't. Your mileage may vary.